# Google Recaptcha v2 is not working with rails application in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, azure, recaptcha

I am using https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/ gem to add Recaptcha v2 in my rails application. This works fine on local-host environment, both in development and production, but when I am using this on VM(Azure VM), it gives ERROR: Stoken Expired issue. 
 
 
Screenshot of the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBpxk.jpg

More details:
  Rails version 4.2.1 
  Passenger Phusion server(5.0) 
  On VM(Ubuntu 14.10), rails application runs on local-host(port:3000) and all  external request on server is redirected to local-host.
 I tried to Google this issue but I am unable to find any solution that works.
Solution I tried: 
 
  setting config.serve_static_files  = true 
  Regenerate keys(Public and private for Recaptcha again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking Date-Time may or may not solve your issue.

This is related to gem version.
Please check this issue on GitHub for complete answer and explanation.

https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/137

Answer (score 4):

We were getting this "ERROR: Stoken expired in google Recaptcha v2" error too.

After days of head scratching it turned out to be the system clock on one of our Windows servers. It was out by around 12 seconds (into the future). When we corrected the machine time the "ERROR: Stoken expired" stopped happening and everything worked perfectly.

Hopefully this will help others suffering from the same issue.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me hours of searching.

Comment: I checked my system, time for postresql, machine time and rails are correct :(

Comment: Thank you, I just encountered the exact same problem! (Made extra confusing by the fact that Recaptcha was working fine on the development/staging servers, but not on production!) All you need to do is reset the system clock, on your server: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342854/what-is-the-command-line-statement-for-changing-the-system-clock

Comment: @TomLord Please add your comment as answer to this question. It works